# Cannot correctly include a third party library with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I cannot seem to correctly include the third party library `nlohmann_json` in my C++ project. Below is my attempt at a CMake configuration. When I go to build however, the line at the top of my `parser.cpp` that tries to `#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"` fails, it says the file cannot be found.

The `CMakeLists.txt` is at the root of the project folder. There is then `src/engine/parser.cpp` and `includes/nlohmann/json.hpp`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(textadv)

set(JSON_BuildTests OFF CACHE INTERNAL "")

add_subdirectory(includes/nlohmann ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/nlohmann_json)

add_executable(textadvexec src/engine/parser.cpp)
target_include_directories(textadvexec PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIRECTORY}/includes)
set_target_properties(textadvexec PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_link_libraries(textadvexec PRIVATE nlohmann_json)
```

Comment: What do you have under `includes/nlohmann` directory? I would assume you have https://github.com/nlohmann/json project here, so you include it with `add_subdirectory`. But you write that you have `includes/nlohmann/json.hpp` file, and this contradicts to my assumption: the `nlohmann_json` project doesn't have `json.hpp` in its root directory.

Comment: If you look in the releases for this project, it seems that you are meant to use only this single .hpp file.

Comment: Yes, you may just download `json.hpp`, place it into subdirectory `nlohmann` and adjust include directories so `#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>` would work. Include directories are adjusted with `include_directories` or `target_include_directories` commands. But `add_subdirecrtory` command, which you use, does completely different things. If you want to use it, see "Embedded" variant in their [documentation](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/README.md#embedded).

Comment: I tried commenting out add_subdirectory, but there's no change. Given my folder structure, I would assume that's how `target_include_directories` is meant to be used.

Comment: Please, update your question post with the **structure of files** in your project. Among other things, that structure should reflect content of `includes` subdirectory... And `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIRECTORY` is a **wrong name** for variable which contains current directory. Proper name is [CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html).